# Amplify - handle console.log in frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify to host for frontend app(React).
I have some `console.log` in the application, which is logged in browser inspector.

Are there any amplify functions/aws services which are able to log it somewhere, 
 instead of logging it in browser inspecter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon's Cloudwatch service to monitor your React application.

Useful readings:

- [Amplify Monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-logs.html)
- [Amazon Cloudwatch User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/WhatIsCloudWatch.html)
- [Milan Gatyas's response regarding similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64118826/12170770)